# Check if (native) feature/class/function (e.g. MediaSource) is available/supported

Tags: dart, dart-html

how can I check using Google Dart if a feature (for example MediaSource) is available.

new MediaSource() throws an error. How to programmatically check if this class or feature exists? Any ideas? Is there an in-build feature for this?

I tried try/catch but it looks like the type of the exception differs on the Browser I use.

**EDIT #2**

youtube.com/html5 does it like this:

```
var mse = window['MediaSource'] || window['WebKitMediaSource'];
setCompatibility('c-mse', !!mse);
```

So should I just use jsobject (dart:js package)?

Regards and Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 3):

I found this:

```
import 'dart:js';
bool available = context.hasProperty('MediaSource');
```

Does anyone have a better solution? To me this looks like the cleanest solution.

Regards, Robert

Answer (score 2):

I think TypeError is thrown, so what about catching the exception if MediaSource doesn't exist?

```
try {
  new MediaSource();
  // do something if MediaSource is available
} on TypeError catch(e) {
  // do something else if MediaSource is not available
}
```

Comment: In Safari I get a 'UnknownJavaScriptObject'.

Comment: I think try-catch is the cleanest solution assuming context.hasProperty() has more overhead regarding dart <-> js exchanges.

Comment: Well there can be a type error after I created the MediaSource object. So I'd have to write another try/catch which is ugly in my opinion. And the check has to be done only once.

Comment: I don't get that point, sorry... you can just check one class at a time and you can also do this only once. If Dart would provide some function to check a class'existence, you would have to call it every time, too.

Comment: After i do `new MediaSource()` the code for using MediaSource follows. For some unknown reason it could happen that a TypeError (that is not thrown btw) occurs. Thus the outer catch block would catch that error and pretend we don't have MediaSource. Thus we would have to write `try { new MediaSource(); try { further code } catch on TypeError (e1) { internal error }  } catch on TypeError (e) { MS is not available }`. This is what I don't like.

Comment: Why do you put all the stuff in one try clause then?

Answer (score 2):

Dart provides special annotation:

```dart
/**
 * An annotation used to mark a feature as only being supported by a subset
 * of the browsers that Dart supports by default.
 *
 * If an API is not annotated with [SupportedBrowser] then it is assumed to
 * work on all browsers Dart supports.
 */
class SupportedBrowser {
  static const String CHROME = "Chrome";
  static const String FIREFOX = "Firefox";
  static const String IE = "Internet Explorer";
  static const String OPERA = "Opera";
  static const String SAFARI = "Safari";

  /// The name of the browser.
  final String browserName;
  /// The minimum version of the browser that supports the feature, or null
  /// if supported on all versions.
  final String minimumVersion;

  const SupportedBrowser(this.browserName, [this.minimumVersion]);
}
```

for example:

```dart
@DomName('ApplicationCache')
@SupportedBrowser(SupportedBrowser.CHROME)
@SupportedBrowser(SupportedBrowser.FIREFOX)
@SupportedBrowser(SupportedBrowser.IE, '10')
@SupportedBrowser(SupportedBrowser.OPERA)
@SupportedBrowser(SupportedBrowser.SAFARI)
@Unstable()
class ApplicationCache extends EventTarget {
 ...
```

You can detect browser version and get(with mirrors) annotation of a class that represents some web feature. If it has `@Experimental` and, probably `@Unstable` then you can't rely on it even with supported browsers. If it has `@SupportedBrowser` annotation  and  users browser is in list or it has no `@SupportedBrowser` at all then you should be ok.

Comment: Still a bit cumbersome, but I like the approach! I hope they add properties that allow to check for supported features more easily.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i think you can make scrip that will import `dart:html` and process it's annotations (with the mirror system) in to something like JSON to avoid runtime overhead.  This script can be a part of the build chain as transformer - for example.

Comment: For MediaSource this does not work. When using the same and identical Version of IE11 on Windows7 and Windows8.1 will produce different results. Because IE11 on Win7 does not support MediaSource while it does on Windows8.1. Thus I'd prefer the runtime check.

Comment: @Robert `MediaSource` has `@Experimental()` annotation so you should avoid using it in the production if you can. But if you absolutely need it then runtime check is the way, but take in mind that your code can break at any moment with browser update or Dart SDK.

Comment: I need it because this is the only way I can get VideoStreaming working in IE11 on Win8.1 for one of our videos - for some unknown reason :/

Comment: @Robert Can you use Flash fallback? I have some bad experience with HTML5 video on IE - its really glitchy. And big streaming platforms like twitch.tv use Flash.

Comment: We could use flash - but it's a bit complicated because we have our own advertising/streaming system behind it. HTML5 Video on IE works fine.